# A solution by contradiction needed for the following problem

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

In convex optimization book the 2.3 problem is as follows

A set $C$ is midpoint convex if whenever two points $a, b$ are in $C$, the
average or midpoint $(a + b)/2$ is in $C$. Obviously a convex set is midpoint convex. It can be proved that under mild conditions midpoint convexity implies convexity. As a simple case, prove that if $C$ is closed and midpoint convex, then $C$ is convex.

Is the following a valid answer for the above question?

Every point on the line can be seen as the average of two other points on that line. Therefore, if for every pair of points their average is in $C$ then we can say that $C$ is convex.

Please correct me where I am wrong in this answer. I will be very thankful to you.

Comment: It's completely wrong.  Every point on a line is the average of two other points on the line, but not necessarily points in $C$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael But if points, whose average is under consideration, are in $C$ then obviously the line joining them must be in $C$ due to convexity of $C$

Comment: But you don't know $C$ is convex.  That's what you want to prove.

Comment: @RobertIsrael yes I do not know that $C$ is not convex. But the above is true only for convex sets. It cannot be true for a non-convex set. So this is kind of contradiction prove. But I am not sure completely.

Comment: @RobertIsrael whats wrong with this logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $x, y \in C$ where $C$ is closed and midpoint convex.

Since $C$ is midpoint convex, all points which can be expressed as $x + \frac{m(y-x)}{2^n}=\left(1-\frac{m}{2^n}\right)x+\frac{m}{2^n}y$ where $m< 2^n, m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$ are in $C$.

Now our goal is to show that  $(1-\lambda) x + \lambda y\in C$, if you can construct a sequence of $m$ and $n$ such that $\frac{m}{2^n} \to \lambda$, then we can use closeness to conclude that $(1-\lambda) x + \lambda y$ is in $C$.

Comment: Thank you so much. $x,y$ are boundary points?

Comment: By definition of convexity, we should pick $x,y$ to be arbitrary point of $C$.

Comment: I am sorry but please explain why closedness is important here. What happens if we remove this assumption?

Comment: Suppose $C$ is a subset of closed interval $[0,1]$ and I tell you that $0,1$ in $C$, we can conclude that points like $0.5$, $0.25$, $0.75$ et cetera  (points that you can reach by bisection procedure) are indeed inside $C$ for sure. but what about points like $\frac1{\sqrt2}$ or $\frac13$? I don't have enough tool to conclude that they are also inside $C$, hence I can't promise that $C$ is convex.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and detailed comment.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not correct and it could not be correct because at no moment you used the hypothesis that $C$ is a closed set. So, if your proof was correct, it would prove that every midpoint convex set is convex.

For instance, $\mathbb{Q}$ is midpoint convex, but not convex.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually, I am unable to understand the solution that is provided in the solution manual of the book. So is there a way to answer the above question through contradiction?

Comment: @FrankMoses Perhaps, but I don't see how. I would prove it directly as it is done [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2761415/446262).